# socketException broken pipe upon upgrading httpclient jar version to 4.5.3

Tags: client-server, httpclient, socketexception

I am getting  socket exception for broken pipe in my client side.

> [write] I/O error: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
>    [LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection::shutdown] http-outgoing-278: Shutdown connection
>   1520546494584[20180308 23:01:34] [ConnectionHolder::abortConnection] Connection discarded
>   1520546494584[20180308 23:01:34] [BasicHttpClientConnectionManager::releaseConnection] Releasing connection [Not bound]

It seems that the upgradation of httpclient jar is causing issue.

Issue is not coming with httpclient-4.3.2

Exception is coming in every 2 minutes.  Issue is intermittent at times.

after , send expect:100-continue ,conn.flush is throwing exception

client and server are Linux machine

client uses http jar to make request to server REST.

Please help me in debugging the issue

can httpjar cause such issue?

Comment: Can anyone please respond on this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The persistent connections that are kept alive by the connection manager become stale. That is, the target server shuts down the connection on its end without HttpClient being able to react to that event, while the connection is being idle, thus rendering the connection half-closed or 'stale'
This is a general limitation of the blocking I/O in Java. There is simply no way of finding out whether or not the opposite endpoint has closed connection other than by attempting to read from the socket.

If a stale connection is used to transmit a request message the request         execution usually fails in the write operation with SocketException and gets automatically retried. 
Apache HttpClient works this problem around by employing the so stale connection check which is essentially a very brief read operation. However, the check can and often is disabled. In fact it is often advisable to have it disabled due to extra latency the check introduces.
The handling of stale connections was changed in version 4.4. Previously, the code would check every connection by default before re-using it. The code now only checks the connection if the elapsed time since the last use of the connection exceeds the timeout that has been set. The default timeout is set to 2000ms